# Move files of certain type from one folder to another

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a PowerShell script that I can run every single morning when my PC turns on that moves all my recently downloaded of type .x from a folder y to a destination z.

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\Temp Downloads" *.gp5, *.gp4, *.gp3, *.gpx, *.fuse -Recurse |
    ForEach-Object { Move-Item $_ -Destination "D:\Guitarpro tabs" -Force }
```

When I run that code, I get this error:

```
Get-ChildItem : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String'
required by parameter 'Filter'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:1 char:14
+ Get-ChildItem <<<<  "D:\Temp Downloads" *.gp5, *.gp4, *.gp3, *.gpx, *.fuse -Recurse | ForEach-Object { Move-Item $_ -Destination "D:\Guitarpro tabs" -Force }
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Comment: since you failed to tell the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet what to DO with the patterns you gave it, it tried to fit things in where the default is ... the `-Filter` parameter is the most obvious ... and it DOES NOT accept a collection. please look at `Get-Help Get-ChildItem -Parameter *` for what the parameters are and what they will accept. [*grin*]

Comment: You probably meant `Get-ChildItem "D:\Temp Downloads" -Include *.gp5, *.gp4, ...`. You also don't need `ForEach-Object` here. Just pipe `Get-ChildItem` directly into `Move-Item`: `... | Move-Item -Destination "D:\Guitarpro tabs" -Force`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers That gives no errors but does not work either

Comment: "Does not work" is not a problem description. How *exactly* did it "not work"? Does `Get-ChildItem` not list the files you want? Does `Move-Item` not move them? What does your modified code look like in the first place? Please [edit] your question to provide this information.

Comment: Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Ceri\Documents" -Include *.gp5, *.gp4, *.gp3 | Move-Item -Destination "D:\Guitarpro tabs" -Force

Does not move the files

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers i added rescure and it worked

Comment: Put `select -expand fullname |` after your pipe. Your trying to move objects instead of a file name. The string error is telling you the object is not a string. You could also replace `$_` with `$_.fullname`

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\Temp Downloads" *.gp5, *.gp4, *.gp3, *.gpx, *.fuse -Recurse |
ForEach-Object { Move-Item $_.fullname -Destination "D:\Guitarpro tabs" -Force }
```

This should do it. You're trying to move objects instead of file names